A function to add spaces before and after a text
I would like to write a function to take a text as input and add spaces before and after the text. I tried \newcommand{\qtextq}{\quad\text\quad} but it does not work. Could you explain how to do so?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\qtext}{\quad\text}
\newcommand{\qtextq}{\quad\text\quad}

\begin{document}

\[
a \qtext{due to} \quad b
\]

\[
a \qtextq{due to} b
\]

\end{document}



\text is a macro which takes one argument. In the first example, you pass the content of the {} to the argument, in the second example, you pass \quad to it and the {...} will just be after it and is again in normal math mode. Instead of just hoping that the correct things might be used as argument, use \newcommand{\qtext}[1]{\quad\text{#1}} \newcommand{\qtextq}[1]{\quad\text{#1}\quad}  instead

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I am aware of the WYSIWYG LaTeX editor TeXpresso. It is very powerful. I wonder if you have some heavy TikZ tex file so that I can test  TeXpresso.

Isn't it based on Tectonic? It's probably very outdated then. Sounds like a bad idea to use.

(if you need tikz-heavy stuff: https://github.com/TikZlings/Extravaganza2023 )

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yess, it is based on Tectonic. Luckily, supporting TeXlive distribution (with pdflatex) is on the roadmap.

How about this?
\newcommand{\qtext}[1]{\quad\text{#1}}
\newcommand{\qtextq}[1]{\quad\text{#1}\quad}

